# digitToInt, wrong datatypes and Unknown Exceptions

Tags: haskell, types, io

I earlier posted almost the same code where I created a lot of errors with lines I didn't even need. [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765415/haskell-type-definitions-not-working)

Now I took away the type signatures and my problems were reduced to 3.
And maybe now I might be able to explain what my problems are.

What ghci shows:

```
C:\Users\MATZE\Desktop\star.hs:8:25:
Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Int'
In the return type of a call of `digitToInt'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: temp <- digitToInt n
In the expression:
  do { temp <- digitToInt n;
       if (((c < 0) && (temp < 6) && (temp > 0))
           || (bs !! c >= temp)) then
           do { return temp }
       else
           do { putStrLn "Ung\252ltige Eingabe";
                .... } }

C:\Users\MATZE\Desktop\star.hs:20:66:
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Char]'
In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `l'
In the first argument of `replicate', namely `(bs !! l)'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `replicate (bs !! l) (" *")'

C:\Users\MATZE\Desktop\star.hs:36:17:
Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
Expected type: [()]
  Actual type: IO ()
In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  putStrLn ("#Spieler " ++ show (pl - 1) ++ "hat gewonnen!")
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn ("#Spieler " ++ show (pl - 1) ++ "hat gewonnen!") }
```

When I try to load this:

```
import Data.Char

board = [5,4,3,2,1]
--getMove :: [Int] -> Int -> IO Int
getMove bs c = do
    n <- getChar
    if isDigit n then do
        temp <- digitToInt n
        if (((c<0) && (temp<6) && (temp > 0))|| (bs!!c >= temp)) then do
            return temp
        else do
            putStrLn "Ungültige Eingabe"
            getMove bs c
    else do
        putStrLn "Ungültige Eingabe"
        getMove bs c

--drawBoard :: [Int] -> Int -> String -> IO String
drawBoard bs l = do
    putStrLn (show ((l + 1)++":" ++ (concat $ replicate (bs!!l) (" *") )))
    if l < 3 then do
        drawBoard bs (l + 1)
    else do
        putStrLn "\n"

--mainloop :: [Int] -> Int -> IO()
mainloop bs pl = do
    line <- (getMove bs (-1))-1

    number <- getMove bs line
    b1s <- take line bs ++ [ ((bs!!line) - number) ] ++ drop (line + 1) bs
    drawBoard b1s 0
    if ((sum b1s) /= 0) then do
        mainloop b1s ((pl `mod` 2) + 1)
    else do
        putStrLn ("#Spieler "++ show(pl -1)++"hat gewonnen!")

--main :: IO()
main = do
    mainloop board 1
```

Why is there a problem with the digitToInt ?

Why does ghci think "l" is a [char] ?

And what does the last Exception even mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow in do notation binds the results of a monadic computation, so

```
do ...
   temp <- digitToInt n
   ...
```

expects `digitToInt n` to have a monadic type, `IO a` in your case. Instead, the way to bind pure values is with `let`:

```
do ...
   let temp = digitToInt n
   ...
```

The second error has to do with the type of `l`, which apparently is inferred to be `String` (a.k.a. `[Char]`). First of all, I recommend that you uncomment your type signature, to make sure that everything has the type that you think it does. In this case the signature for `drawBoard` should have one fewer argument,

```
drawBoard :: [Int] -> Int -> IO ()
```

The actual reason for the error is the mismatched parentheses `show ((l + 1)++":"++...`, here you concatenate `(l + 1)` with a string. You probably meant to write `show (l + 1)++":"++...`.

The third error is similar to the first, you should write

```
let b1s = take line (bs ++ [ ((bs!!line) - number) ] ++ drop (line + 1) bs)
```

instead of using an arrow.

Finally you are trying to use `...-1` to subtract from a monadic computation that returns a number. You first need to bind the result of the computation, and then subtract 1. Or you can use `fmap`/`liftM` to do this.

As a stylistic suggestion: all of your code lives in the IO monad, while much of it doesn't have to. For example, you can draw a board to a String, and then print it in one go.

Comment: Thank you. That actually helped a lot, not just for this code but also in understanding some stuff I really didn't get in haskell.